# Divergence in interaction between induced dipoles

Tags: electrostatics, dipole-moment

Suppose I have two polarizable point-particles 1 and 2 arranged on the z-axis and separated by $r$. Each particle has a dipole moment $\mathbf{p}_i=\alpha \mathbf{E}_i$. If we apply an external field $E_\mathrm{ext}$ also along the z-axis, then by symmetry the moments must point along $z$. A dipole's field along its axis is $\mathbf{E}_p = \frac{2\mathbf{p}}{r^3}$. By symmetry we know the x and y components of each $\mathbf{p}$ are zero, so the problem reduces to two scalar equations:
$$  p_0 = \alpha \left ( \frac{2p_1}{r^3} + E_\mathrm{ext} \right ) $$
$$  p_1 = \alpha \left ( \frac{2p_0}{r^3} + E_\mathrm{ext} \right ) $$
which are solved by
$$ p_0 = p_1 = \alpha E_\mathrm{ext} \left (1 - \frac{2\alpha}{r^3} \right )^{-1} $$.

Not only is the solution singular at a special (finite) separation, but the sign flips so the induced dipoles actually oppose the external field at small separations. You can get out of the singularity by including nonlinear terms in the polarization, but I'm not sure you can get out of the sign flipping. And anyway, there would still be a special point in the solution where the response becomes nonlinear regardless of the strength of the external field.

It's also weird because we usually assume that we can model polarizable media with the discrete dipole approximation - treating chunks of volume as point dipoles. With strong polarizability, the separation between points in the approximation might be less than the critical value $(2\alpha)^{\frac{1}{3}}$, and then weird things can happen.

So is this physical? Did I make an obvious mistake? I can't see anything wrong with it mathematically.

Comment: Neither monopole nor dipole interaction at r=0 is physical. These are the distances at which classical electrodynamics breaks down and where one would need quantum (field) theory. Sadly, even in quantum theory these divergences lead to non-trivial problems, but at least those can be normalized away (or removed with a UV cutoff). I am not aware that there is a rational procedure that can get rid of the divergence of classical monopole and dipole interactions. A theorist may want to chime in on that, though!

Comment: Look at the result again. It is singular at finite distances.

Comment: Even with induced dipoles you can't get energy out of nowhere (but out of the work that is performed by the field and by moving the dipoles closer together). Did you make the symmetry argument as an educated guess or does it follow from actually minimizing the total energy of the system?

Comment: The z-axis symmetry is the result of solving the six linear equations governing the dipoles. Because the dipoles themselves aren't allowed to move, energy conservation occurs microscopically. That's what goes into the $\alpha$ in the first equation: the cost of displacing electric charge inside each dipole. So I'm not sure that energy is a very useful way of thinking about the problem.

Comment: I should clarify that as the dipole moments increase, from a macroscopic point of view we are losing energy, not creating it. Two aligned dipoles have negative interactions. Presumably the missing energy goes into the internal degrees of freedom of the dipoles.

Comment: I don't think one can get a divergence from a properly formulated linear model either way. Why you assume that energy is not a useful quantity is not clear to me. Intuitively I would guestimate that  there may be a large distance solution which is unstable as we push the dipoles closer together, but instead of the total energy diverging, one of the dipoles will turn around to minimize the total energy of the solution to something finite. Try that scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Polarizability of a small particle is proportional to volume, i.e. to $a^3$, where $a$ is some characteristic radius. So the weird behavior happens only for distances $r$ comparable to $a$. But such distances necessarily implies that higher multipoles will become important rendering the underlying dipole approximation inaccurate. Using strongly polarizable materials we can somewhat increase the critical $r/a$ but it will also increase the strength of multipoles, so they will remain important for larger $r$ as well.

To conclude this part, the point dipole is a convenient model, but it has limitations with respect to distance to observer ($r\gg a$), while some internal size $a$ always exists even if it is not explicitly specified. If a realistic model is considered, e.g. two slightly separated metallic spheres (with sufficient number of multipoles in numerical calculation) - it may have non-trivial dependence on the separation distance. Some of the observed features may even be qualitatively similar to the weirdness you see in the dipole model, but I have not checked that.

Concerning the discrete dipole approximation (DDA), the problem is alleviated by the fact that *many* dipoles are used. And to have good numerical accuracy, one usually tries to make dipole size (or, equivalently, their separation) small compared to any characteristic size of the particle. That means that most dipoles will be inside the bulk (locally homogeneous medium), then they are surrounded by other dipoles. And the electrostatic interaction of these dipoles (with similar polarizabilities) largely cancel each other. Numerically, this is exemplified by the convergence of the spectrum of the DDA interaction matrix to that of the integral operator with increasing number of dipoles (for fixed particle). However, using the DDA with only *a few* dipoles may indeed lead to weird results (non-physical eigenmodes/frequencies). By contrast, the DDA with a *single* dipole is almost perfect representation for a small sphere.